# IIS или Apache + PHP максимально производителен на Windows Server?

Tags: php, windows, apache, iis

Я не могу найти в интернете ни крупицы инфы / бенчмарков по PHP в Windows. К сожалению, из-за политики компании нет возможности поставить в интранете Linux или хотя бы виртуалку. Подскажите, что тут лучше:

- IIS + FastCGI
- Apache + mod_php + mpm_winnt
- Apache + FastCGI

Comment: Nginx + php-fpm. На винде тоже можно развернуть.

Comment: @ilyaplot проверял, использует только 1 ядро и только 1 рабочий процесс. Даже у них в FAQ написано, что под виндой криво работает

Comment: Да, я тоже уже прочитал. Жаль.